# how to enter value into website inputs by excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to enter a value in a website filter, I can enter the username and password in login page by using the HTML element ID, after login I want to enter a value in filter input, the filter input id is units-grid-search-filter, but it automatically changed to units -grid -search -filter,
I don't the problem is in wherein element id space or delay
this is my code.

```
Sub Button3_Click()



On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "http://103.215.211.2/Web/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fWeb%2f#25/-3/"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.Navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLdoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLdoc.all.UserName.Value = "abc"
HTMLdoc.all.Password.Value = "abc123"

HTMLdoc.all.units -grid - Search - Filter.Value = "123"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
Debug.Print oHTML_Element.Name
Next
Set frm = HTMLdoc.forms(0)

frm.submit

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop




e.Click

Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I am not clear what the problem is. Are you saying the id changes to have spaces? You try either of the following ie.document.querySelector("input[id*=search]").value = "xyz" or ie.document.querySelector("#units-grid-search-filter,[id='units -grid -search -filter']").value = "xyz"   if either of those work I will type up an answer explaining. Though from what you show you should just be able to use ie.document.querySelector("#units-grid-search-filter").value = "xyz"

Comment: It also looks like you may need associate a key down event with the field entry. Site appears to be using knockoutjs.

Answer (score 1):

The site you are trying to automate is using knockoutjs.

The Textbox in which you are trying to set the value using your VBA code is set as **observable** in knockoutjs code.

> If this parameter is an observable value, the binding will update the
>   element’s value whenever the value changes. If the parameter isn’t
>   observable, it will only set the element’s value once and will not
>   update it again later.
>
> Whenever the user edits the value in the associated form control, KO
>   will update the property on your view model. KO will always attempt to
>   update your view model when the value has been modified and a user
>   transfers focus to another DOM node (i.e., on the change event), but
>   you can also trigger updates based on other events by using the
>   valueUpdate parameter described below.

Reference:

[The "value" binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)

Which means the value is coming from the knockoutjs model. If you modify the value manually then it will also modifies the value in model.

When you are trying to assign the value using your VBA code, no events occur and value not get updated to that model.

I tried to fire an event from VBA code. but it is not modifying the value in model. I tested with multiple JS events and it did not worked. If you try to pass the same event from your HTML code then it will give an error in VBA.

At last, I suggest you to make a test with **Sendkeys**.

Sendkeys is essentially the same as typing with the keyboard. You need to make sure the correct windows and objects are selecting before proceeding. Sendkeys can also trigger events that run based on user interaction on the web.

Sample code:

```
  Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long) As Long

Sub demo()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True

    URL = "example.com"

    IE.Navigate URL

    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    HWNDSrc = IE.HWND
    SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

    IE.Document.getElementById("abc").Focus
    SendKeys "123", True

    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your requirement.

Comment: Please try to provide a detailed information like which object it ask for? Please try to check that you are using 'IE' as InternetExplorer object. If you are using any other name then you need to modify it in code. Let us know about the testing result.